# How to filter list of all objects in Unity project, by their type?

Tags: unity

I want to filter the list of project objects in unity, and view all objects of specific type in the project. (by type, not by name)
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

In the search bar simply type "t:" followed by the type. also "l:" can be used for filtering by label.

If you need more control over the search, use AssetDatabase.FindAssets in an editor script.
more info in the following link:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.FindAssets.html